# How to check headers of most recent response in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

Our application has a feature where you can press a button, wait for a while, and then get some information after it's been delivered. It'll send about 10 responses with identical url's and only the last one should have the information we care about in it. My script right now is:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.server()
    cy.route('get', /waiting_for_response/).as('response')
  })

  it('checks for good data', function() {
    cy.get('.get-data').click()
    cy.wait('@response', {timeout:10000}).then((xhr) => {
      expect(xhr.responseHeaders.data).to.not.be.a('null')
    })
  })
```

This always fails since cy.wait is resolved on the first matching url and only the last response's headers have a data value of not null. Is there a way to wait for all of the responses to have come back before checking if any of them were not null? Or perhaps specify the route has to have a certain response header in order to match? Any help or ideas would be super appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can break the problem into smaller conditions

- cy.wait(10000)
- check length of cy.get('<>').should('have.length', 10)
- now you can check condition expect(xhr.responseHeaders.data).to.not.be.a('null')

You can refer to documentation 
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing

Section: Making multiple requests to the same route